# Python and Berkeley DB versions in RedHat Enterprise Linux 6.6, 6.7 and 7.x

Tags: python, redhat-enterprise-linux

I need to know what versions of Python and Berkeley DB are installed with RHEL 6.6, 6.7 and 7.x.

If several versions of Python are available (for instance, Python 2.7 and 3.3) I would need to know too.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded the ISOs myself and installed them in a virtual machine.

I see this:

- **Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.6:** Python 2.6, Berkeley DB 4.7.
- **Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7:** Python 2.6, Berkeley DB 4.7.
- **Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7:** Python 2.7, Berkeley DB 4.7 included for compatibility only, not actually used anymore in the system.
- **Ubuntu 12.04:** Python 2.7, Berkeley DB 4.8 (legacy, compatibility) and Berkeley DB 5.1 (the version actually used with the stock applications).